# Rotate an image in a PictureBox with a value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a program that displays the rotation of a Wii Remote with a PictureBox. When the Wii Remote rotates on the X axis, the picture of a Wii Remote will rotate as well. The value of rotation is already displayed in a text box, and it looks something like this: `0.109243284720305` or `-0.132414335`.

How would I use those values to rotate the displayed image?

Comment: How about check if < 0, then rotate left and > 0 so rotate right, or which ever way it supposed to rotate.

Comment: I don't know how to rotate the image itself is the problem. Plus it shouldn't just say if 'left' or 'right', it should display the analog rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom control inheriting from PictureBox and overriding the OnPaint virtual method to paint the wiimote bitmap as you need:

```
 public partial class WiiMoteControl: PictureBox {

    public Bitmap wiimote;
    private float _angle;
    public float Angle { 
         get { return _angle; } 
         set { _angle = value; Invalidate( ); } 
    }

    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs pe ) {
        base.OnPaint( pe );
        pe.Graphics.ResetTransform( );
        pe.Graphics.TranslateTransform( Size.Width / 2, Size.Height / 2 );
        pe.Graphics.RotateTransform( Angle );
        pe.Graphics.TranslateTransform( -Size.Width / 2, -Size.Height / 2 );
        if (wiimote != null) {
            pe.Graphics.DrawImage( wiimote, 0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I implement this? Do I create a custom control? I'm not sure where to put this code.

Comment: Adding this code as a class to your project and resolving its dependencies, will add the control to the toolbox, and you will able to use it in design mode to add the control to a form

Comment: Okay, i'm really bad at this. What do you mean by resolving dependencies?

Comment: Adding the required "usings"

Comment: In theory, everything should be correct, but I keep getting the error in which it is impossible to add the control to the form. I have it set to All CPUs and all that jazz, oh well, might as well give up.

Comment: I don't know why.. but I have prepared you a project with the control that works fine https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59983887/WiiTest.rar

Comment: I'm using a 64 bit machine and building with the 64 bit version of vJoy, by the way. I'll try your project and then try using a different vJoy library.

Thanks for writing all of the code for me, it was a great help!

Comment: It turned out that I was building with All CPU, and I should have been building with x86. Also, I should have the wii remote connected when working on this...